# Getting an error while trying to use a command under the lifecycle tag on kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubectl

im successfully running kubernetes, gcloud and postgres but i wanna make some modifications after pod startup , im trying to move some files so i tried these 3 options

1

```
 image: paunin/postgresql-cluster-pgsql
      lifecycle:
        postStart:
          exec:
            command: [/bin/cp /var/lib/postgres/data /tmpdatavolume/]
```

2

```
image: paunin/postgresql-cluster-pgsql
      lifecycle:
        postStart:
          exec:
            command: 
              - "cp"
              - "/var/lib/postgres/data"
              - "/tmpdatavolume/"
```

3

```
image: paunin/postgresql-cluster-pgsql
      lifecycle:
        postStart:
          exec:
            command: ["/bin/cp "]
            args: ["/var/lib/postgres/data","/tmpdatavolume/"]
```

on option 1 and 2, im getting the same errors (from  **kubectl get events** )

```
Killing container with docker id f436e40f5df2: PostStart handler: Error ex
ecuting in Docker Container: -1
```

and on option 3 it wont even let me upload the yaml file giving me this error

```
error validating "postgres-master.yaml": error validating data: found invalid field args for v1.ExecAction; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false
```

any help would be appreciated! thanks.
pd: i just pasted part of my yaml file since i wasnt getting any errors since i added those new lines

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the [document about lifecycle hooks](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/container-lifecycle-hooks/) you might find useful.

Your option 1 won't work and should give you the error you saw, it should be `["/bin/cp","/var/lib/postgres/data","/tmpdatavolume/"]` instead. Option 2 is also the right way to specify it. Can you `kubectl exec` into your pod and type those commands to see what error messages that generates? Do something like `kubectl exec <pod-name> -i -t -- bash -il`

The error message shown in option 3 means that you're not passing a valid configuration to the API server. To learn the API definition, see [v1.Lifecycle](http://kubernetes.io/docs/api-reference/v1/definitions/#_v1_lifecycle) and after a few clicks into its child fields you'll find `args` isn't valid under `lifecycle.postStart.exec`.

Alternatively, you can find those API definition using `kubectl explain`, e.g. `kubectl explain pods.spec.containers.lifecycle.postStart.exec` in this case.

Comment: Thank you very much! it did work just fine with the first change `["/bin/cp","/var/lib/postgres/data","/tmpdatavolume/"]` ,  how can i add more commands?, also thanks for the api and the link!

Comment: To add more commands, you have 2 options: 
1. Add a script to your image and call that script, or 
2. Change it to `command: ["sh", "-c", "<cmd 1>; <cmd2>; ..."]`